# Google Analytics cross domain tracking doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I have tried to make cross domain tracking work between my website and FastSpring for a month but can't find the problem. I tried lots of variations of the code an nothing seems to work.I also contacted FastSpring support but their answers didn't fix the problem

I suspect it may be a problem of my site using GaTracker while FastSpring uses GA but I really don't know. I checked with Google tag assistant and cross domain tracking sometimes work but not always, it's strange.

I'm trying to get it to work from this page:

https://frenchtogether.com/course/

```
window.ga = __gaTracker;    __gaTracker('create', 'UA-43334717-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker':true});
    __gaTracker('set', 'forceSSL', true);
    __gaTracker('linker:autoLink', ['fastspring.com'] );
    __gaTracker('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    __gaTracker('require', 'displayfeatures');
    __gaTracker('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
    __gaTracker('send','pageview');
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that autolink isn't set on fastspring.com?